# visual studio 2010 not generating .so file in firebreath plugin

Tags: firebreath

I have created firefox plugin using firebreath in windows 7 with visual studio 2010. its generating .dll, .msi and .exe file for windows but not .so file for linux. I have to use this plugin for both OS so how should I create it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must build the linux version on a linux machine, mac os version on a mac os machine, and windows version on a windows machine.

The build/ folder should not be in source control; it will be platform specific and generated by cmake in the prep script.

Comment: Might be able to cross compile.

Comment: It might be possible to cross-compile from windows; definitely not from one of the other platforms. I'd guess the best chance would be to cross-compile to linux (building a firebreath plugin on mac os x pretty much requires xcode, thought it does partially work with makefiles), but it'd take a lot of work to set up the environment and it's outside of my experience and I haven't heard of anyone doing so with FireBreath